# Where I can find the source code for Raspberry Pi 4 images

Tags: arm, source, arm64

Images are available for download at:

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Where I can find the source code to build such images?

Comment: Essentially what you need is [live-build](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Live-Build). The list of packages are in [the manifest files](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/20.04/release/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are on the latest Ubuntu version 20.10 (Groovy)
The source code for groovy can be downloaded in two ways
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-groovy

Or via enabling src packages in /etc/apt/sources.list and doing a
apt install linux-source

However you are correct the build instructions for ubuntu are well out of date and I've not succeeded in building one from scratch yet.